# How to check if a given date is not end of week, end of month and end of Quarter using java

Tags: java, jodatime

1. How to check if a given date is not end of week, end of month and
   end of Quarter

   should not be End of week, end of month and end of Quarter

Comment: Isn't it sufficient to show that the date is not on the last day of month to cover the quarters of the year?

Comment: Hints: `java.time.LocalDate`, `java.time.DayOfWeek`, `java.time.YearMonth`, `org.threeten.extra.YearWeek`, `org.threeten.extra.YearQuarter::atDay` and `::atEndOfQuarter`.

Answer (score 1):

Here a partial answer:

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate endOfMonth = today.dayOfMonth().withMaximumValue();
System.out.println("Today is end of month: " + today.equals(endOfMonth));
```

Note that a similar simple solution is not possible for quarters because Joda-Time does not support that element (workaround or other library necessary). Furthermore, a similar solution for calendar weeks using `weekOfWeekyear()` instead of `dayOfMonth()` is possible as long as you want ISO-8601-compatible calendar weeks which start on Monday and have at least 4 days within calendar year (this excludes US-weeks!).

Comment: i didn't knew you could find the end of month so easily with `LocalDate`

Answer (score 0):

For the week end you can use:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(ts*1000l, DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")));

Integer newTs = (int) (dt.withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY).getMillis()/1000);

if(newTs == ts){
  // it's end of the week
}
```

Using [joda-time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) lib and where `ts` is your timestamp (int), similary you can use `withDayOfMonth` to check if it's the end of month.